# Pinstripe displaying on Boss's tablet

Tags: html, css, windows, tablet, styling

Essentially I have [this site](http://www.contedia.com) which displays fine on all my browsers, and online tools to check, but my boss's tablet renders an odd line **in the footer**.

And it's *only the boss's tablet*, all other browsers, including my iPad, Windows Phone, Laptop, and Desktop display it correctly, as well as multiple emulators.

I've played with the margins, and nothing; there are no borders to speak of.

It's got me stumped, and I've been doing this for over a decade.  Why does it have to be on his machine!?

Have a play around in the inspector/debugger.

(cannot post the image just yet - not enough rep)

Comment: there is a border-bottom on your .home .content article:first-child selector

Comment: Except that is the on the home page, within the content section, and for the first article only.
I'm dealing with the footer, and that styling does not apply.

I really wish I could have posted the image.

Comment: the style is correct. But, you have to make it available for window width 767px or below.
use media query with max-width: 767px

Comment: When you refer to your boss's tablet, Provide the model and os that it's on and i already answered your question below.

You can easily upload an image on any "Image Upload" service and get the link back here.

Comment: All my media queries at max-width, and the styling you are talking for is in the 1024 - I'm not using 767.

Answer (score 0):

In your file **template.css**, Look at the **line 422** where it says

```
.home .content article:first-child { border-left:0; border-right:0; border-bottom:.1em solid #ccc; }
```

Replace it with

```
.home .content article:first-child { border-left:0; border-right:0; border-bottom: 0; }
```

*Reference Image*

[image: Reference Image]

## UPDATE

I noticed that on screen size 768 or smaller, You are adding a border-bottom for the same class

```
.home .content article:first-child
```

In your file **template.css**, Look at the **line 425** where it says

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

Replace it with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
     .home .content article:first-child {
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
        border-bottom: .1em solid #ccc;
}
```

*Reference Image*

[image: max-wdith: 768]

So you have now removed the border-bottom property from the *@media query 1024* and added that property in *@media query 768*

That should do the trick.

Comment: That is for the content's articles - literally, it is only for the first article on the home page, and nothing else.

The problem I am having is with the footer, there is just a gap.

Comment: Still applies.  There is not a second border-bottom in 768px.

Comment: Talking on the 1024 width, You don't have to have a border-bottom property because your layout is not completely changed as it does on the 768 and when it changes to a different layout your border-bottom that was implemented on max-width 1024 actually works, So there is no need to define it in the max-width 1024 and instead you have to do this under the 768 media query since max-width 1024 will create the odd line on top of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

is this the line you're referring to? if yes, please your media query to `max-width: 767px;` 
[image]

Comment: Refer back to my answer, It's already explained and there is no need to replace 1024 width to 768 as the stylesheet contains both width separately.

Comment: No, it's not.

I know about that bug, mainly in Safari - not the 'priority'.

Comment: can you please mail the image to bootstrapissue@mailinator.com ?

Comment: It's not the BUG but the poor implementation of your logic, It's being displayed no matter what OS you are on, I currently tested on Windows and Mac platform together.

It might have got a little lower on the UNKNOWN tablet you are referring too, Please specify the exact issue otherwise your question is getting too broad

Comment: sorry, I think the issue is with the tab. but, please refrain from using harsh sentences. Thank you.

Comment: Your boss's tablet is displaying the website as it's on a desktop or larger screens and since your footer tag is repeating, Chances are that the browser is adding an extra padding/margin between both of these tags. **Avoid using any sentence that may cause your question to remain unanswered**

Comment: So is that why I've been downvoted?  Because you guys have taken offence?

I made it clear that I was talking about the footer, yet you give me solutions for something that doesn't help?

Comment: I don't know the tablet make and model.
Yes I did - you need a certain level of rep to post images.
Yes I did - I just made it **bold** to stand out.

I would love to know how you would have written this question, given such limits placed on me.